# asp.net mvc. How to return modified via ajax view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having a problem with ajax.
Here is the code.

**Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public long requestedVar { get; set; }
    public string ReturnedDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**View**
Name: AddNewInfo

```
   <head>
   <script>

    $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
            closeText: "Закрыть",
            prevText: "&#x3C;Пред",
            nextText: "След&#x3E;",
            currentText: "Сегодня",
            monthNames: [
                "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
                "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"
            ],
            monthNamesShort: [
                "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
                "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"
            ],
            dayNames: ["воскресенье", "понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота"],
            dayNamesShort: ["вск", "пнд", "втр", "срд", "чтв", "птн", "сбт"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Вс", "Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб"],
            weekHeader: "Нед",
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ""
        };
    </script>
    <script>
    var GlobalVar1=0;

    $("#dropdownlist1").change(function getID() {
    <some code>
    GlobalVar1 = selectedValue;
    alert(GlobalVar1);

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("myMethod1", "Home")",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: { requestedVar : GlobalVar1},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('OK');
            $("html").html(result);
        },  
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDirectionID, new SelectList(Model.DirectionList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.DirectionName }), "Value", "Text"),"", new { @class = "Duration", required = "required", id="dropdownlist1" })
        @Html.ActionLink("+", "_AddDirection", "Home", null, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-success"})
        <div>@Html.DisplayName("Choosen description")</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReturnedDescription, new { @class = "Duration", disabled = "disabled" })</div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult myMethod1(ViewModel m)
    {
        var db = new DB();
        ModelState.Clear();

        var returnedVal = db.GetDesctiption(m.requestedVar).First();
        m.ReturnedDescription = returnedVal.Description;

        var vm = DataFactory.Refresh();
        vm.ReturnedDescription = m.ReturnedDescription;

        return View("AddNewInfo", vm);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

**How it all works now:** 
ajax successfully sends a POST-request with data, my controller return view, this view showing in browser, but the returned view not contains any JS scripts.

**The is question:**
How to return to browser fully View with JS scripts too and ReturnedDescription value?

Answer (score 0):

For recovering data by Ajax with MVC pattern, you shoud return a JSON (for example) type´s data from the controller, for after recovering it in view by ajax.

You have to use:

```
return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Instead of:

```
return View("AddNewInfo", vm);
```

Completed code would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult myMethod1(ViewModel m)
{
    var db = new DB();
    ModelState.Clear();

    var returnedVal = db.GetDesctiption(m.requestedVar).First();
    m.ReturnedDescription = returnedVal.Description;

    var vm = DataFactory.Refresh();
    vm.ReturnedDescription = m.ReturnedDescription;

    return Json(vm,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Be care about the method where you are using this code. Should be the which one where you are requesting data by Ajax call.

Beside, I would send data from ajax call in json type:

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
```

Completed code will be (if you send data by json type, you will recover it by string type as well):

```
<script>
    var GlobalVar1=0;

    $("#dropdownlist1").change(function getID() {
    <some code>
    GlobalVar1 = selectedValue;
    alert(GlobalVar1);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("myMethod1", "Home")",
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Sending complete");
            },  
            error: function (error) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step I**

Change your Action method and return a **Json Result**.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult myMethod1(ViewModel m)
    {
        var db = new DB();
        ModelState.Clear();

        var returnedVal = db.GetDesctiption(m.requestedVar).First();
        m.ReturnedDescription = returnedVal.Description;

        var vm = DataFactory.Refresh();
        vm.ReturnedDescription = m.ReturnedDescription;

        return Json(vm,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Step II**

Change your ajax success option.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("myMethod1", "Home")",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: { requestedVar : GlobalVar1},
        success: function (data) {
           if(data.ReturnedDescription){
              $('#ReturnedDescription').val(data.ReturnedDescription); // This line to be noted.
           }
           // alert("Sending complete");
        },  
        error: function (error) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

**Also don't forget to keep your code inside $(document).ready**.

Comment: Hi, Anadi. The task is to show in browser the complete view with styled text and with TextBoxFor with ReturnedDescription value.

Comment: In that case you $.ajax will not work. You have to use Ajax.Beginform. Update your question with 'AddNewInfo.cshtml' so that I can update my answer.